# Visual Studio 2010 Shell (isolated) - can it be removed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have Visual Studio 2010 (isolated) installed on our development SQL server and our security team have picked it up as a vulnerability. They want it updated or removed

I cant actually see it in program files to update it
Can someone explain what this software does and if its tied in somehow with SQL and is it OK to remove it?
Once removed do I need to install an updated version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSMS is dependent on Visual Studio 2010 (isolated). So if you uninstall it, SSMS may not work. you will have to download New SSMS and reinstall it. if there is any third part plugin installed on SSMS, that will also go and will have to reinstall on new SSMS.

I am trying to find a way to see if we can upgrade existing visual studio 2010 to a higher version to remediate the vulnerability.